# What is neuroph GUI import file format?

Tags: neural-network

Just starting with Neuroph NN GUI. Trying to create a dataset by importing a .csv file. What's the file format supposed to be? 
I have 3 inputs and 1 output so I assumed the format of the import file would be ..

1,2,3,4
6,7,8,9

But I get error 9, or 4 or 10 depending on what combination I try of newlines, commas etc.

Any help out there ?

many thanks,
john.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you aren't counting with the output column. The lastest columns are for the output.

So, for example, if you have 10 inputs and 1 output, your file will need to have 11 columns.

I came here, because the Neurophy can't import CSVs with title line. Example of a data file that works for me:

```
1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,2.0,2.0
1.0,3.0,3.0
1.0,4.0,4.0
1.0,5.0,5.0
1.0,6.0,6.0
1.0,7.0,7.0
1.0,8.0,8.0
1.0,9.0,9.0
1.0,10.0,10.0
2.0,1.0,2.0
2.0,2.0,4.0
2.0,3.0,6.0
2.0,4.0,8.0
2.0,5.0,10.0
2.0,6.0,12.0
2.0,7.0,14.0
2.0,8.0,16.0
2.0,9.0,18.0
2.0,10.0,20.0
```